# Elastic Beanstalk has not load balancer setting in the configuration menu

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image]

I am trying to enable websocket over my Elastic Beanstalk application yet after I follow the instruction here (https://mitchellsimoens.com/websockets-behind-elastic-beanstalk/), I find my application's health is degraded. This is probably because I failed to find load balancer setting in the configuration menu mentioned in this instruction.

Here is a screenshot of my configuration menu:

[image]

Obviously, the websocket isn't working for my application. In fact the entire application is down after I added the `.ebextensions/files.config` to my project. Of course, my process.env.PORT is 80 instead of 3000 (I think, not sure where to look).

I've tried these two settings:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_websockets.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content : |
      upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:process.env.PORT;
        keepalive 256;
      }
      server {
        listen process.env.PORT;
        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          # prevents 502 bad gateway error
          proxy_buffers 8 32k;
          proxy_buffer_size 64k;

          proxy_pass http://nodejs;
          proxy_redirect off;

          # enables WS support
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
      }

files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_websockets.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content : |
      upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:80;
        keepalive 256;
      }
      server {
        listen 80;
        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          # prevents 502 bad gateway error
          proxy_buffers 8 32k;
          proxy_buffer_size 64k;

          proxy_pass http://nodejs;
          proxy_redirect off;

          # enables WS support
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no load balancing setting for `Scaling > Single instance` type EB, what you did is pretty much spot on, however:

By default, you need to listen to 8080 rather than 80 (AWS is confusing like that), and need to send your traffic to whatever port you are using, in this case, 80, so...

Also you need to delete the old nginx_confg and restart the instance/server.

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_websockets.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content : |
      upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:80;
        keepalive 256;
      }
      server {
        listen 8080;
        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          # prevents 502 bad gateway error
          proxy_buffers 8 32k;
          proxy_buffer_size 64k;

          proxy_pass http://nodejs;
          proxy_redirect off;

          # enables WS support
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
      }
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/41_remove_eb_nginx_confg.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content : |
      mv /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf.old
```